# Help on Probabilities

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I have $2$ tests I'm struggling with and I'd really appreaciate if you could help.

The questions are:

$(1)$ - A city suffers every year, on average, $5$ earthquakes, $2$ large fires and a flood. What is the probability that next year there will be at least one disaster?

$(2)$ - General strikes at federal universities are relatively rare events with a strike averaging every $5$ years. What is the probability of having at least one strike next year?

Here's what I've done so far.

$Q1$ - I tried using Poisson, which gave me coefficient $8$, then did a Sum from $1$ to $8$ using Poisson probability formula but the answer I get is not even close to the right answer.

$Q2$ - I tried using Poisson as well, which gave me the coefficient $\frac{1}{5}.$ Since on average there is only $1$ strike in $5$ years I did Poisson for just 
$1$, since if there is $2$ strikes it will break the average strike rate. It gave me $0.163746.$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

1) You have to find the complement of no disaster happening.  Also, not specified but my guess is the events are independent of each other, so there will be three separate Poisson variables.  The result should be close to 50%.

For independent events $A$ and $B,\, p(A \& B) = p(A)p(B)$. You can extend this for three events. The events you should be looking is that for a particular disaster not happening (independent of each other).  Note that, without this assumption this problem is not solvable since joint probabilities are not given.

2) Same reasoning, complement of not a single event happening.  What is the probability of no strikes?

Comment: Hello Karafka, For Q1 I really have no clue how to compute, unless the 3 separate Poisson variables you meant are 1/8, 2/8 and 5/8. As for Question 2 it really makes sense, if I did compute right the Poisson variable it should be P=1-e^(-1/5) which is 0.18127, it has this answer as answer out of 5 possible answers, but it also has the 0.163746. But taking a second look what you said makes a lot more sense than what I did.

Comment: Karafka, thanks for the code. 
I compiled it and my answer is not even close to that 0,46 I get from your Haskell code.
I am sorry for being such a novice but, can you elaborate more how to come with this answer?
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, the hint is correct but code was wrong. Probability of at least one of three is: 1 - p(no earthquake && no fire && no flood) = 1 - P(5;0)P(2;0)P(1;0) where P(m,x) = e^-m m^x / x! is possion.